# Azure API App adds extra Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

It appears that when deploying an web app as an Azure API App, it adds an extra Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header to the response. How can I override and remove this?

My project uses SignalR and OWIN, when I add or change the Access-Control-Allow-Origin through the requests or setup in my own code, I get to specify another Access-Control-Allow-Origin header property, but the additional wildcard (*) header is always added as well.

This makes my requests to SignalR fail, as it includes authentication header which is not allowed when origin is *.

API Apps are hosted behind the "API app host", I presume that is the origin of this additional header. Is there any way I can modify this behavior?

Note: the additional header is NOT present when deployed as a regular Azure Web App.

Answer (score 0):

this may be because you have the MS_CrossDomainOrigins app setting set in addition to having CORS enabled in your backend.  If so, please remove one or the other.

Thanks.

Comment: There are no MS_CrossDomainOrigins app settings key for the API App Host. I can try to set it to a specific domain, or is it possible to set it to empty string to make it not return at all?

The API App does not use WebAPI, it only hosts SignalR and the Cors-setup is with SignalR. I presume it's SignalR that returns one of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers, and I do think it will auto-generated the value based upon origin of the caller.

Maybe the API app needs to do some WebAPI code to enable the proper Cors-settings?

Answer (score 0):

Watch out do not have set up in your web.config something like this:

```
<httpProtocol>
 <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 </customHeaders>
```

Delete it if it exists.